# How to push without the default --mirror option in a mirror repo

Tags: git

For some reason, I must create a mirror repo to the central repo.

central repo <-----> mirror repo <-----> dev repo

**The risk** is that pushing in a mirror repo may overwrite the histroy of the central repo.

If someone (Mr J) pushs a new commit(commit_X) into the central repo and at the same time the mirror is going to push without a fetch, then this push will overwrite the histroy of the central repo. As a result, the commit_X will be deleted.

Mr J will need to pull, merge and push his commit_X again.

The rootcause is if a repo is created with `clone --mirror`, the `push` will implicitly use `--mirror` by default even it is not added after `push`.

I know it is possible to install a hook script to disable `push --mirror` in centrol repo side.

But is there a way to disable it in the mirror repo side?

**[EDIT1]** Added an illustration to help you with understanding this question.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a mirror repo, nor just a bare repo?

Comment: Please give us example command line commands used and indicate which command wipes out the changes by Mr J.  I do not believe I understand your question completely.

Comment: Why is there a picture full of text instead of text in your question?

Comment: It's a screenshot. And because it contains some special characters so I added this as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit your `.git/config` and unset `remote.<remote>.mirror`, as is explained in `git help push`:

> **--mirror**
>   Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under refs/ (which includes but is not limited to refs/heads/, refs/remotes/, and refs/tags/) be mirrored to the remote repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end. This is the default if the configuration option remote..mirror is set.

Comment: Thanks. By setting mirror to false in the config file, the push does not use --mirror implicitly now. But will it affect fetch or any other operations in the mirror repo since it is created with clone --mirror ?

Comment: according to `git help config`, this should not have any side-effects.